# mysql query quote signs

Tags: mysql

I am a newbie to mysql. I am confused by the quotes signs.

In mysql query

Does it make any different between

> CREATE DATABASE 'mydatabase';

and

> CREATE DATABSE mydatabase

One with quote, the other without
Also with Insert and other commands

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it makes no difference. (Except that you have a typo in the latter command with word DATABASE.) If you had used a reserved keyword as the database name, you would have had to quote it.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html